# angularjs routeProvider is not working / not invoking the controller at all

Tags: angularjs, web-services, rest

I am trying to implement the route functionality using angular js. Unfortunately the route functionality is not working at all. I tried many options and re-checked the code for syntax errors etc. but no luck..

Here is my code.

**html code:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.17/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>


     <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
     <script src="index.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body ng-app="App">
   <div ng-controller="AppController as ctrl">
   <header>
   <h1> Restaurants Explore</h1>
   <h4> Way to explore the menus</h4>
   </header>

    <nav>
    <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="entry in arrayOfObjects"><a href="#" ng-click="ctrl.displayRestaurant($index)">{{entry.name}}</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
   <section ng-model="restaurant">

   <div>
   <table>
    <tr><td><a href="#menu">Menu Details</a></td></tr>
   </table>
   </div>
   <div ng-view>
   asdfslajfdsjfdl
   </div>
   </section>
   </div>
   </body>
```

**index.js**

```
var module = angular.module("App",['ngResource','ngRoute']);


module.factory("mywebservice",function($resource){

        return $resource("http://localhost:8080/MyWebService/myweb/msgservice");
}); 

module.controller("menuController", function($scope,$routeParams){

    alert();
    /*$scope.arrayOfObjects = mywebservice.get({restId:$routeParams.restId}).$promise.then(
        function(response){
            alert(JSON.stringify(response));
            },
        function(error){
            alert(error.message);
        }   
    );*/

});


module.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){

        alert("Inside router provider");
        $routeProvider.
        when('/menu',{
            templateUrl:"templates/menu.html",
            controller:'menuController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo:'/'
        });
    }
    ]);

module.controller("AppController", function($scope,mywebservice){

    $scope.arrayOfObjects = mywebservice.query().$promise.then(
        function(response){
            $scope.arrayOfObjects = response;
            },
        function(error){
            alert(error.message);
        }   
    );

    this.displayRestaurant=function(index){
        $scope.restaurant = $scope.arrayOfObjects[index];
    }

});
```

---

Nothing works.. any clues... i am running these app from tomcat webservice. The application is trying to fetch somedata from teh REST webservice and displays it in the browser.

Comment: what is the expected result? are there any error messages? It looks like your `<a>` tag isn't set to go anywhere.. try:

`<a href="#/menu" ng-click="ctrl.displayRestaurant($index)">{{entry.name}}</a>`

Comment: nope... infact the controller which is linked to my url in the route is not being invoked. I have put an alert message as the first statement in the controller its not working...